# onClick event not working on a React app, not even with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a modal component that displays some pictures. The modal is triggered when you click on the leading image. The leading image component is the following:

```
const LeadingImage = ({ handleOpen, photos }) => {
  return (
    <ImgWrapper>
      <PropertyImg onClick={() => handleOpen(0)} src={photos[0]} />
    </ImgWrapper>
  );
};

export default LeadingImage;

// Style
let ImgWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

let PropertyImg = styled.img`
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: auto;
  pointer-events: inherit;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

The onClick event used to work the first time I wrote this code, but it stopped working out of the blue. Now whenever I click on the PropertyImg, there is no activity in the console. The DOM doesn't detect any click whatsoever. The cursor doesn't turn into a pointer when hovering over the leading image either.

The code for the handleOpen method is the following:

```
const handleOpen = async index => {
    await setShow(true)
    setIndex(index)
    console.log("Clicked!")
  }
```

Any idea on what may be the root cause of this behaviour?

EDIT:

This is the component where LeadingImage is rendered. It's an abridged version:

```
const SelectedProperty = ({ propertyList }) => {
  // Hooks
  const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.user)
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleOpen = async index => {
    await setShow(true)
    setIndex(index)
    console.log("Clicked!")
  }
  const handleSelect = selectedIndex => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex)
  }

  // Route params
  let params = useParams()

  // Main variables
  var currentProperty = propertyList[params.id]
  var photos = currentProperty.media.photos

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <PropertyRow>
        <PropertyCol xs={8}>
          <LeadingImage handleOpen={handleOpen} photos={photos} />
        </PropertyCol>
          // More stuff
      </PropertyRow>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default SelectedProperty;

let Wrapper = styled.div`
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
`;

let PropertyCol = styled(Col)`
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px 20px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px lightgrey;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: -10;
`;

let PropertyRow = styled(Row)`
  width: 100%;
  .modal-content {
    width: 900px;
    max-width: 90% !important;
  }
  z-index: -9999;
`;
```

Comment: Especially because you wrote "it stopped working out of the blue". Did you maybe use something new in the layout, e.g. a div that possibly covers all your content (something like position: fixed, lefT: 0, top: 0, width: 100vw, height: 100vh)? Those can block mouse events for underlying non-child elements... Did you have a look into element inspector to see if anything blocks the mouse events?

Comment: I think you will need to share more code. I copied your LeadingImage and your handleOpen and it worked perfectly for me. How and where are you rendering LeadingImage ?

Comment: `The cursor doesn't turn into a pointer when hovering over the leading image either` sounds like you have an invisible div covering your button trapping the click

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I have tried finding an invisible div on top of these components and I couldn't find anything. I have added the code of the component where the LeadingImage component is rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem its in your `PropertyRow` style - you are setting an index of -9999. So when you click on image, you not really clicking in it but actually on the div parent.

You can check this just commenting the z-index.

```css
let PropertyRow = styled(Row)`
  width: 100%;
  .modal-content {
    width: 900px;
    max-width: 90% !important;
  }
  /* z-index: -9999; */
`;
```

Comment: Obrigado Luis! The z-index was indeed the issue.